# OpenLayers 2 and RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, openlayers, dependency-management

I have recently moved from using a single JS file for a module to using RequireJS. Needless to say I'm using OpenLayers2 in that module.

I've 'required' Openlayers2, and Require JS simply doesn't acknowledge its existence.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
require.config({
  shim:{
    openlayers: {
        exports: 'OpenLayers'
    }
  },
  paths: {
    jquery: 'plugins/jquery/jquery.min',
    openlayers: 'plugins/OpenLayers/OpenLayers'
  }
});
require(['openlayers'], function(test) {
   console.log('OL: '+test);
   console.log('Vector' + test.Layer.Vector);
});
```

The first log simply returns a `null` value.

The second log throws an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Layer' of null`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was simply using a very old version of RequireJS... So it was my own fault haha thanx for the help Bill!

Answer (score 0):

Strange that you're having this problem, because this is working fine for me on JSFiddle:

```
require.config({
  shim:{
    openlayers: {
        exports: 'OpenLayers'
    }
  },
  paths: {
      jquery: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min',
      openlayers: 'http://www.openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers'
  }
});

require(['openlayers'], function(test) {
   console.log('OL: '+ test);
   console.log('Vector' + test.Layer.Vector);
});
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/FdL2S/

Could it be a version problem? Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: I thought so too, but after adapting my version by using direct URLs it still outputs `OL: null`.
I think it might be due to the asynchronous loading of dependencies by RequireJS. Do you know a quick fix to make this specific `require` happen synchronously? Perhaps that might work?